# Does pose estimation require non co-planar points?

Tags: opengl, opencv, computer-vision

I am a newbie to computer vision.
I have been reading some research papers and also came across this
implementation of pose estimation, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit .

Now it seems that to estimate the pose, at least 4 points of correspondence from
object to image space is required. And it is required that these points are
*co-planar*.

Now, I have seen some implementations (ALVAR / ArUCo)where in case of a planar
marker we find the pose.

They use OpenCv API, SolvePnP().

Links,
http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26)
http://virtual.vtt.fi/virtual/proj2/multimedia/alvar/index.html

I am now wondering what is the foundation algorithm for SolvePnP. Pls clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`cv::SolvePnP()` allows the use of three different algorithms. From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp):

> Method for solving a PnP problem:

```
CV_ITERATIVE Iterative method is based on Levenberg-Marquardt optimization. In this case the function finds such a pose that minimizes reprojection error, that is the sum of squared distances between the observed projections imagePoints and the projected (using projectPoints() ) objectPoints .
CV_P3P Method is based on the paper of X.S. Gao, X.-R. Hou, J. Tang, H.-F. Chang “Complete Solution Classification for the Perspective-Three-Point Problem”. In this case the function requires exactly four object and image points.
CV_EPNP Method has been introduced by F.Moreno-Noguer, V.Lepetit and P.Fua in the paper “EPnP: Efficient Perspective-n-Point Camera Pose Estimation”.
```